# Downloading encypted m3u8 chunks ?

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8, m3u

Is it possible to download AES encrypted m3u8 chunks If so then how to do it
?

[m3u8 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kuikg5aYynBpEic69gSnMSupnoAPtbuI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Exactly the same as downloading non encrypted chunks.

Comment: It's not working can you elaborate more

Comment: Yes this is possible using ffmpeg / vlc / programming. What is your approach and what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some additional information including the IV (Initialization Vector) and key file from the HLS child playlist

1. curl the child playlist and find the IV (Initialization Vector)
2. Download the key file for the segment and copy the IV value for use later in the terminal
3. Hex decode the .key file using hexdump command line -  `Xxd <keyname>.key`
4. Download a ts segment contained within the playlist
5. Use the following openssl command to take an input of the original encrypted file, and use the IV value and the hex decoded .key value for -iv and -K values respectively.

`openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in video-file.ts -out video-file_1.ts -nosalt -iv <iv_value> -K <decoded_key>`

Now you should be able to view the decrypted chunk.

Note: You need `openssl` and `Xxd` command line tools

This post describes the process of doing similiar but combining multiple segments
https://idof.medium.com/download-and-decrypt-aes-128-m3u8-playlists-495c12d6543a